# wordpress CheckPassword and Warning: substr()

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, hash

I'm still newbie for wordpress, I'm just trying to check password (I'm sure I missed something somewhere but I'm feeling lost and couldn't focus):

```
$user = $_POST['user_name'];
$pass = $_POST['user_password'];
$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);

$result=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM Materials WHERE mtrname= '$user' ");
if($result){

$pwd=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT password FROM Materials WHERE mtrname= '$user' ");
if($wp_hasher->CheckPassword($pass, $pwd)) {
    echo "YES, Matched";
} else {
    echo "No, Wrong Password";
}
}
```

it's always showing

> No, Wrong Password
>
> Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-phpass.php on line 124

I know CheckPassword function must receive only String and I'm giving Array, any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$pwd` is an array, it should be a string. 
Change [get_results](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) to [get_row](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/)

And

```
$pwd=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT password FROM Materials WHERE mtrname= '$user' ");
```

becomes

```
$pwdQuery=$wpdb->get_row("SELECT password FROM Materials WHERE mtrname= '$user' ");
$pwd = $pwdQuery->password;
```

Comment: like this, I don't get the warning message anymore but it still shows me "No, Wrong Password" and I think because $_POST['user_password'] is already an Array too

Comment: You can `var_dump($_POST['user_password'])` to see its type. Or you can add the HTML form being submitted in your original question.

Comment: get_row doesn't work it shows this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/widget.php(64)

Comment: I edited my answer `$pwdQuery['password']` to `$pwdQuery->password`. Give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check password of particular user then you can use Wordpress Default function to check

Please check the code below

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//Here i retrieve the user information through email you can also retrieve user information through **username**
$user = get_user_by('email', $email);

$ID = $user->ID;
$user_login = $user->data->user_login;
$user_pass = $user->data->user_pass;

if(!wp_check_password($password, $user_pass, $ID)){ 
    //bad password
 }else{
 //Correct information
}
```

Comment: thanks but I'm using a custom table in database so I dont think $user->data->... will work in this case :/